# How to use where clause on multiple nested eager loading in Laravel 5.8.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have four tables that are having relationships form the first to the last where 
users is a parent to village on **applicant_id** , Village to Cell on **village_id** , Cell to Sector on **cell_id**

and my eloquent query is as follows and it works perfectly without a where clause, when where clause is added I get an error: 
**Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'applicant_id' in 'where clause'**

```
      // joins users , village ,cell and  sector
          $uvcsector = SectorApproval::with('Cell.Village.UserApplicant')
            ->where('applicant_id', 10)
        -> get();
```

**Models :**

```
        class Users extends Model
    {
   protected $table ="users";
    public function VillageApplicant(){
    return $this->hasMany(VillageApproval::class);
   }
 }


class VillageApproval extends Model
  {
  protected $table ="villageapplication";
     // OnetoOne relationship inverse
     public function UserApplicant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class, 'applicant_id');
   }

   // One Village application can be sent in one cell  (OnetoOne)
    public function Cell(){
       return $this->hasOne(CellApproval::class);
    }
  }


 class CellApproval extends Model
   {
  protected $table ="cellapplication";
    // OnetoOne relationship inverse
    public function Village()
    {
   return $this->belongsTo(VillageApproval::class, 'village_id');
   }
   // One Cell application can be sent in one sector  (OnetoOne)
   public function Sector(){
    return $this->hasOne(SectorApproval::class);
   }
  }


class SectorApproval extends Model
  {
   protected $table ="sectorapplication";
   // OnetoOne relationship inverse
   public function Cell()
   {
   return $this->belongsTo(CellApproval::class, 'cell_id');
  }
   }
```

Comment: Please give the models screenshot...

Comment: @TanvirAhmed, thanks I modified the body and I added the Models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereHas` to search in the related tables.

```
$uvcsector = SectorApproval::with('Cell.Village.UserApplicant')
            ->whereHas('Cell.Village.UserApplicant', function($query) use ($id){
                $query->where('applicant_id', $id);
            })
            -> get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->where('village.application_id', 10)
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?. This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers